# PowerShell copy-item check destination for same file name before copying

Tags: powershell

I have a script that

1. Sort files and folders.
2. Copy sorted files recursively and selectively in to multiple locations while checking free space.
3. Rename the extension some of those copied files.

Script running smoothly. But if I run the script twice, Copy portion copies duplicate files, since some extensions are renamed. (Problem only happens with renamed extensions only)

I can't think of a better way than get each file while recursing and extracting the basename and checking against existing files in the destination. But there are thousands of files to handle. so it won't be efficient.

**Directory structure:**

- Main
- SUB1

  - date1
  - date2
  - date3

    - folder1
    - folder2
    - folder3
    - folder4

      - file_1.extension
      - file_2.extension
      - file_3.extension
- SUB2

  - date1
  - date2
  - date3

    - category_1
    - category_2
    - category_3

      - sub_cat_1
      - sub_cat_2
      - sub_cat_3

        - file_1.new_extension
        - file_2.new_extension
        - file_3.new_extension
- For every date of the month I have each and every file and folder under it.
- I copy files from SUB1 in to SUB2

This is my one of my copy function:

```
$threshold = 100    
function Copy-1 {

$rmainingSpace = Get-FreeSpace

if($rmainingSpace -gt $threshold)
        {
           $Source = "source\path"

                Copy-Item ($Source) -Destination "destination\path" -Filter "*.extension" -recurse -Verbose 

                Copy-Item ($Source) -Destination "some\other\destination\path" -Filter "*.another_extension" -recurse -Verbose 

            $rmainingSpace = Get-FreeSpace

        }
        else
        {
            Pause($rmainingSpace)
            Copy-1
        }
}
```

- Pause function pause script until presses Enter. So that if disk space ran out, I can clear space and continue the rest of the script.
- There are few other copy functions similar to this one. I use multiple copy functions, to copy into different locations according to which file needs to go where basis.

Much Appreciated if anyone can help with this.
Thanks.

Comment: 1) why are you changing the extensions?  2) why are you changing the extensions such that it's not the same as what you changed it to the first time?  seems not doing 1 or 2 could solve your issue.

Comment: `Copy-Item` isn't checking if the target Item exists. It justs overwrites what ever is there... You need to check every Item yourself with `Test-Path` and `if` `$false` you tell `Copy-Item` to do its job. Thatway you will safe some time, too.

Comment: @KoryGill, As per my requirement I need to change some of the extensions. Not changing is not an option.

Comment: @T-Me, good thought. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

As [Kory Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329137/kory-gill) comments, I also don't see why you want to change extensions on the files.
My idea would be to add a sequential number on a file's basename if the destination file should already exist.
In fact, if you manually try to copy/paste a file that already exists, Windows too suggests adding a sequence number to the file.

For that this function might prove useful:

```
function Copy-Unique {
    # Copies files to a destination. If a file with the same name already exists in the destination,
    # the function will create a unique filename by appending '(x)' after the name, but before the extension. 
    # The 'x' is a numeric sequence value.
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$SourceFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$DestinationFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [string]$Filter = '*',

        [switch]$Recurse
    )

    # create the destination path if it does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$DestinationFolder'"
        New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType 'Directory' -Force | Out-Null
    }
    # get a list of file FullNames in this source folder
    $sourceFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter $Filter -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
    foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {
        # split each filename into a basename and an extension variable
        $baseName  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)    # this includes the dot

        # get an array of all filenames (names only) of the files with a similar name already present in the destination folder
        $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder -File -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
        # for PowerShell version < 3.0 use this
        # $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

        # construct the new filename
        $newName = $baseName + $extension
        $count = 1
        while ($allFiles -contains $newName) {
            $newName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $baseName, $count, $extension
            $count++
        }
        # use Join-Path to create a FullName for the file
        $newFile = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $newName
        Write-Verbose "Copying '$file' as '$newFile'"

        Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $newFile -Force
    }
    if ($Recurse) {
        # loop though each subfolder and call this function again
        Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object {
            $newSource = (Join-Path -Path $SourceFolder -ChildPath $_)
            $newDestination = (Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $_)
            Copy-Unique -SourceFolder $newSource -DestinationFolder $newDestination -Filter $Filter -Recurse
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest some changes in your `Copy-1` function to use the above `Copy-Unique` function:

```
function Copy-1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$Source,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Destination,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [int]$Threshold,

        [string]$Filter = '*'
    )

    # you are not showing this function, so I have to assume it does what it needs to do
    $remainingSpace = Get-FreeSpace

    if($remainingSpace -gt $Threshold) {
        Copy-Unique -SourceFolder $Source -DestinationFolder $Destination -Filter $Filter -Recurse -Verbose
    }
    else {
        $answer = Read-Host -Prompt "Remaining space is now $remainingSpace. Press 'Q' to quit."
        if ($answer -ne 'Q') {
            # you have cleared space, and want to redo the copy action
            Copy-1 -Source $Source -Destination $Destination -Filter $Filter
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
Copy-1 -Source 'source\path' -Destination 'destination\path' -Threshold 100 -Filter '*.extension'
Copy-1 -Source 'source\path' -Destination 'some\other\destination\path' -Threshold 100 -Filter '*.another_extension'
```

---

***NOTE***

Of course, running this over-and-over again with the same parameters, you would end up with a lot of copies, because the function does not compare files for equality. If you want to do a true folder synchronization, I suggest you use dedicated software for that or use RoboCopy.
Examples of directory synchronization using RoboCopy can be found almost everywhere on the internet, like for instance [here](https://improve.dk/simple-file-synchronization-using-robocopy/)

Comment: Adding a sequence number is a brilliant idea. In that even if there are duplicates I can identify them easily. Thanks mate.
Also thanks for the advice on my copy function.

Comment: Sometimes there are reasons to change file extensions... I once had a TV that was able to record movies to HDD. It saved them with its own file-extension but it was just a covered mp4. I just changed the extension on all of them and could play them on a PC.

Comment: Copy-Unique was what I was looking for.  I may modify it to return the filename(s) copied.  You saved a lot of effort on my part.