# Rename files with Powershell, file name already exist

Tags: powershell, rename

I try to rename in batch files in multiple folders by removing - .extension

Example files:

- test file 1 - 1234.docx
- test file 1 - 4321.docx
- test file 1 - 6789.docx

For this I run the following script:

`Get-ChildItem  -recurse -exclude .dxl | foreach {
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName (($_.BaseName -replace '(.)-.*?$','$1') + $_.Extension) }`

This will give me the following error:

> "Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

How can I get rid of this by adding (1), (2), (3) if the file already exist after renaming?

Comment: Something like this `while (Test-Path $f) { $c++ ; $f="$n ($c)"}`

Comment: `Test-Path` will let you check to see if the file already exists. Instead of immediately trying to rename, assign the expression you're passing to `-NewName` to a string variable instead, then use `Test-Path`, and modify the value of the string variable until `Test-Path` tells you that it _doesn't_ exist - then do the `Rename-Item`.

Comment: Have a look at my [Copy-Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233702/9898643) function. Hope that helps.

Comment: the answer has been accepted so i assume the posted solution is working if not reply and i may have an alternate answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came up with for this problem:

```
$FileTracker = @{}
$files = (Get-ChildItem  -recurse -exclude "*.dxl" -file | sort fullname).fullname
$files | foreach {
    $Base = (($_ | select-string -pattern "(.*)-.*?$").matches.groups[1].value).Trim()
    if ($FileTracker[$Base]) {
        Rename-Item -path $_ -newName ((split-Path $Base -Leaf),"($($FileTracker[$Base]))",($_ -replace ".*(\..*?)$",'$1') -join "")
        $FileTracker[$Base]++
    }
    else {
        $FileTracker.add($Base,1)
        Rename-Item -path $_ -newName ((split-path $Base -Leaf),($_ -replace ".*(\..*?)$",'$1') -join "")
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that this solution looks to make files unique in their respective directories. If it sees `test file 1 - 23.txt` in two different directories, it will rename them both to `test file 1.txt`. If you already have files that have been renamed like `testfile 1(1).txt` and `testfile 1(2).txt`, there will be issues with this working. So I need to know if that is a condition.

Comment: Two remaining issues with this, it's not excluding .dxl files AND if there are file with two - in the file name it's not only cutting part after last "-".

Comment: And if there are multiple files like: - 1234 , - 2314, -2231 it also fails:(

Comment: Sadly this does not solve the issue completely. For two type of files it is not working.

- files like // - 12457 >> result in: - 12457(1)
- files like // Re_testfile test - test - test - 12458 >> result in: Re_testfile test

Comment: When you have a file like "testfile test - test - test - test - 1223.docx," how do you want it to be renamed?

Comment: Only want to remove the last part - <number>, so everything after the last "-".

Comment: Any suggestions? @AdminOfThings

Comment: I did make a few updates. Test this and let me know what still doesn't work.

Comment: if I run this for multipe folders and the folders inside those folders I get a lot of errors which I didn't face with a small test set. "Cannot rename file because it does not exist